How can I create a Vue 3 component library that depends on an another npm package?
I am working on creating a Vue 3 library that incorporates another external npm vue3 library. While the setup seems correct, I am facing issues when trying to utilize both libraries together, resulting in errors. I have followed the necessary steps to integrate the external npm library into my Vue 3 project, but when attempting to use them in conjunction, I encounter errors that hinder the functionality. I am seeking guidance on how to properly configure and utilize an external npm library within a Vue 3 library to avoid these errors and ensure seamless integration. Any insights, tips, or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
